# In a unit test, how can I replace a interface method on a domain object?

Tags: grails, groovy, junit

I'm using Groovy 1.8.6 and Grails 2.1.1

I have a interface

```
public interface Searchable{
    Long docVersion()
}
```

Implemented by a object

```
class Book implements Searchable {
    Long docVersion() {
        System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
    }

    String otherMethod() {
        "toto"
    }
}
```

And a test

```
@Mock([Book])
class SomeBookTester {
    @Before
    void setup() {
        Book.metaclass.docVersion = {-> 12345}
        Book.metaclass.otherMethod = {-> "xyz"}
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
        assert 12345 == new Book().docVersion()
    }

    @Test
    void test2() {
        assert "xyz" == new Book().otherMethod()
    }
}
```

The first test always fail because the methode replacement dosen't work. How could I fix this? What's the probleme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

I change the class like that:

```
class Book implements Searchable {
    Long docVersion() {
        currentTime()
    }

    Long currentTime() {
        System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
    }

    String otherMethod() {
        "toto"
    }
}
```

And in the test, I replace the **currentTime** method

```
@Mock([Book])
class SomeBookTester {
    @Before
    void setup() {
        Book.metaclass.currentTime= {-> 12345}
        Book.metaclass.otherMethod = {-> "xyz"}
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
        assert 12345 == new Book().docVersion()
    }

    @Test
    void test2() {
        assert "xyz" == new Book().otherMethod()
    }
}
```

Tests passes

Comment: Is there a groovy/grails known bug about that?

Answer (score 2):

You better use a proper GrailsMock facilities. You may try this:

```
@Mock([Book])
class SomeBookTester {
    @Before
    void setup() {
        def mockBook = mockFor(Book)
        mockBook.demand.docVersion(0..1)  { -> 12345 }
        mockBook.demand.otherMethod(0..1) { -> "xyz" }
        Book.metaClass.constructor =  { -> mockBook.createMock() }
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
        assert 12345 == new Book().docVersion()
    }

    @Test
    void test2() {
        assert "xyz" == new Book().otherMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I just try it and the result is exactly the same, test1 failed

Comment: Edited method multiplicity.

That's strange. I've tested with both Grails 2.1.3 and Grails 2.2.0. Both working fine for me.

Comment: I'm using 2.1.1, maybe it was fix after